# Difficulty reading binary files in c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a visual c++ project named ***Search Elements*** in which there is a class called ***PeriodicTable*** and I have another visual c++ project called ***Write Elements*** in which there is this same class and it's description(variable names and their sizes) is same too...

I use the ***Write Elements*** project to write the object of the class ***Periodic Table*** to a binary file named ***PeriodicTable.dat*** but whenever I use the binary file with my ***Search Elements*** project(basically just copy-paste from *Write Elements* to *Search Elements*) then the output is unexpected(contains garbage value).

In my opinion the file should work with both the projects as both the projects contains the same class decription. But I don't know what is the problem???

***Write Elements Code:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class PeriodicTable
{
    char Name[15], Symbol[3], Block, State[10], Colour[15], Classification[20];
    int GroupNo, AtomicNo, PeriodNo;
    float Weight;

    public:

    void GetInfo();
};

int main()
{
    PeriodicTable ptele;
    ofstream fileout;

    fileout.open("PeriodicTable.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);

    system("cls");
    ptele.GetInfo();
    fileout.write((char *)&ptele, sizeof(ptele));

    fileout.close();

    return 0;
}

void PeriodicTable::GetInfo()
{
    cout << "Full Name of the element: ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Symbol: ";
    cin >> Symbol;
    cout << "Block: ";
    cin >> Block;
    cout << "State(at Room Temperature): ";
    cin >> State;
    cout << "Colour: ";
    cin >> Colour;
    cout << "Classification: ";
    cin >> Classification;
    cout << "Group Number: ";
    cin >> GroupNo;
    cout << "Atomic Number: ";
    cin >> AtomicNo;
    cout << "Period Number: ";
    cin >> PeriodNo;
    cout << "Atomic Weight: ";
    cin >> Weight;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `WriteElements` code sample ?

Comment: Also, Visual studio implies windows - what are you using to do the file reads/writes? Special care must be taken if you use fopen, for instance, so that it doesn't try to translate line endings at the wrong moment.

Comment: That's the first time I see Visual C++ projects with such a naming convention. This is... disturbing...

Comment: Why do you use binary when you have ... json ?

Comment: json?? I didn't understood what you said!!

Comment: @TheDreamCoder17 Binary is hard to debug and maintain, why don't you use a standard easy format like ini/xml and, especially, json? Except if it is a test/school project or something ... and it seems to be the case.
You should also provide the `read` code (from the other project).

Comment: And how do you read this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It perfectly works for me with the following read code:

```
int Read()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("PeriodicTable.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);

    while (0 == file.rdstate())
    {
      PeriodicTable ptele;
      file.read((char *)&ptele, sizeof(ptele));
      //if (0 == file.rdstate())
      //    ptele.PrintInfo();
    }
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not perform class abstraction correctly. And more over, everything in same file? including class definition? That's not how you use VS project structure.

I assume you want to create two separate applications. One would create periodic table and a second application use the file generated by first application.

If above is correct, you need to declare the PeriodicTable class in header, implement constructor, destructor and GetInfo method in a .cpp implementation. Another .cpp implementation should contain your main() function for the first application.

Note that it is generally a good idea to create a universal header file in a shared location by two applications which contain global definitions, like the path to the generated .dat file. In this case, absolute path should be taken as both applications will unlikely have same relative path to the file.

Another thing to notice, instead of letting compiler figure out how the file should be structured, structure it yourself. Follow the structure convention you created in both application. One suggestion is that instead of writing `(char *) &ptele`, write one line for one element, give a tab between each column, say between Element and Symbol. You'll need to parse it properly before using the value but this avoids any ambiguity of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you use the VS project structure correctly. At the first sight your simple solution should contain one project that would contain one class (PeriodicTable) and this class should have several methods e.g. searchElements, writeElements, readElements etc. What is wrong with this approach? If, for some reason, you cannot use this approach, then I think you should better explain your problem, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Okay See!! Sorry if I am being rude... But I want to use the binary file I created using the _**Write Elements project**_ and use it with the _**Search Elements**_ project which has the same class description...

Comment: I replied to your first version where you did not even provide your code so I was really confused trying to undersatnd what you want to do. Seeing the other comments around I was not obviously the only one. If you want to get answer you need to post a good question first. Being rude or nervous about the answers that you did not expect will not help.